# How do you update column value based on other column values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I have this data frame:

```
df

Server   Port
Ser123   Ethernet3
Ser123   Ethernet4
Ser123   Ethernet12
Ser123   Ethernet567
Serabc   Ethernet2
Serabc   Ethernet34
Serabc   Ethernet458
Serabc   Ethernet5689
```

I need to create another column based on values on Port column. I need to check if the number single digit after Ethernet (fir example Ethernet2) then function_val column value be '5k', if the the number Ethernet is double digit like Ethernet34, then the function_val should be 10k etc. I need to be able check for three digits so forth.

Data frame needs to be like this:

```
Server   Port        function_val
Ser123   Ethernet3    5k
Ser123   Ethernet4    5k
Ser123   Ethernet12   10k
Ser123   Ethernet567  20k
Serabc   Ethernet2    5k
Serabc   Ethernet34   10k
Serabc   Ethernet458  20k
Serabc   Ethernet5689 20k
```

I tried this, any ideas how I could do this better and most efficient way?

```
df['function_val']=np.where((df.Port.str.contains("Ethernet[0-9]"),'5k', df['function_val'])
```

Comment: Can you provide all conditions? What are the cutoff points?

Comment: Starts with Ethernet, then single digit ot 2 digit or 3 digit after

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) to get the number and [`cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) to assign labels from bins:

```
bins = [0, 10, 100, np.inf]
labels = ['5k', '10k', '20k']

df['function_val'] = pd.cut(df['Port'].str.extract(r'(\d+)$', expand=False)
                                      .astype(int),
                            bins=bins, labels=labels)
```

Output:

```
   Server          Port function_val
0  Ser123     Ethernet3           5k
1  Ser123     Ethernet4           5k
2  Ser123    Ethernet12          10k
3  Ser123   Ethernet567          20k
4  Serabc     Ethernet2           5k
5  Serabc    Ethernet34          10k
6  Serabc   Ethernet458          20k
7  Serabc  Ethernet5689          20k
```

Alternatively, if you want to [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) values strictly from the number of digits, you could `extract` the number as above, then count the digits with a [`log10`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.log10.html)+[`ceil`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ceil.html) transformation:

```
labels = {1: '5k', 2: '10k', 3: '20k', 4: 'other'}

df['function_val'] = (np.ceil(np.log10(df['Port'].str.extract(r'(\d+)$',
                                                              expand=False)
                                         .astype(int)+1))
                        .map(labels)
                     )
```

Example:

```
   Server          Port function_val
0  Ser123     Ethernet3           5k
1  Ser123     Ethernet4           5k
2  Ser123    Ethernet12          10k
3  Ser123   Ethernet567          20k
4  Serabc     Ethernet2           5k
5  Serabc    Ethernet34          10k
6  Serabc   Ethernet458          20k
7  Serabc  Ethernet5689        other
```